# Intellij 14 does not support bea 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, bea

I have to work on an old project with **java 1.4 and bea 8.1**

By configuring the server I realize that

> WebLogic versions prior to 9.0 are not supported

What are the possible alternatives for configuring/debugging this environment?

- Should I use an earlier version of the IDE? (Which should I use be between the latest?)
- Is there the possibility to use the server, for example, remotely?

Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I found was to use a **remote configuration** from IJ.

I modified startWebLogic inserting JAVA_OPTIONS (as suggested in the same screen IJ) that is to say:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005,%JAVA_OPTIONS%
```

choosing transport socket on localhost: 5005.

The main drawback is the deployment that need to be done outside the IDE and the log panel that is not docked.